# How to execute sql user defined function using c#?

Tags: c#, sql

how to execute sql user defined function using c# same as that of executing stored procedure

Comment: I thought it would have, no matter ill delete comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like any other sql. Here's an example:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.IsInteger(@value);", con))
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "10";
    bool isInt = (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

`dbo.IsInteger` is a [scalar-valued function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131043.aspx) which returns a `bit`(true/false).

For the sake of completeness and even if it's not really related, here is it:

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[IsInteger](@Value VarChar(18))
Returns Bit
As 
Begin

  Return IsNull(
     (Select Case When CharIndex('.', @Value) > 0 
                  Then Case When Convert(int, ParseName(@Value, 1)) <> 0
                            Then 0
                            Else 1
                            End
                  Else 1
                  End
      Where IsNumeric(@Value + 'e0') = 1), 0)  
End
```